# SQL Server 2012 - Query Qptimization Slow Index scan on small table (6 records)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a SQL Server database and want to optimize my most commonly executed query.

The database is quite simple it tracks the status of delivery orders leaving my plant. for the purposes of this question let's assume that my DB only contains 4 tables, the first is the Delivery Master table, containing the delivery ID(int), type(tinyint), location(tinyint), and status(tinyint), the other three tables are lookup tables to correlate the numbers used for type, location, and status to a text string (e.g. Status: 1='Open', 2='Picking',3='On-Dock'...)

The most commonly executed query is the delivery summary (Which is on the main page of the web-application) it is a pivot of all Deliveries witht he row fields being the type and location and the column headings being status:

```
[Location]  | [Type]  | [1(Open)] | [2] | [3] | [4] | ...
----------------------------------------------------------
'LocationA' | 'TypeA' | 1         | 2   | 3   | 4   | ...
'LocationA' | 'TypeB' | 5         | 6   | 7   | 8   | ...
'LocationB' | 'TypeA' | 9         | 10  | 11  | 12  | ...
...
```

On average this query takes 100ms to run (Which is odd as much more complicated queries that perform date calculations on every row in the Master Table and aggregate on more fields with weighted averages take less time than this query which only counts rows)

When I look at the execution plan I see that over half of the execution time is spent performing a clustered index scan on a table that has **6 records** (Type).

The warehouse (Location) table scans using a non-clustered index and takes up only 3% of the execution time (But that table is only 5 records, which I am *sure* makes a huge difference)

I created a nonclustered index on the type table but the query optimizer does not uses it even when I delete the old execution plan and force it to create a new one.

Here is the SQL that is being executed

```
SELECT TOP (500) 
    Warehouse, WarehouseDescrip, Type, TypeDescrip, 
    [1] AS Open_DO, [2] AS In_Process, [3] AS On_Dock, [4] AS Revision, [5] AS Complete
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Static.Warehouse.Description AS WarehouseDescrip, 
         Static.DOType.Description AS TypeDescrip, 
         DOInfo.DOMaster.Status, DOInfo.DOMaster.DONum, 
         DOInfo.DOMaster.Type, DOInfo.DOMaster.Warehouse
     FROM  
         DOInfo.DOMaster 
     INNER JOIN
         Static.DOType ON DOInfo.DOMaster.Type = Static.DOType.ID 
     INNER JOIN
         Static.Warehouse ON DOInfo.DOMaster.Warehouse = Static.Warehouse.ID
     WHERE 
         (DOInfo.DOMaster.Status <> 6)) ps 
PIVOT 
     (COUNT(DONum) FOR Status IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS pvt
ORDER BY 
     Warehouse ASC, Type ASC
```

Screenshot of the execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression instead of the PIVOT?  That might have better performance.

Comment: Maybe you've got some weird disk fragmentation that's got that table spread out all over the disk.

Comment: How would I fix this disk fragmentation issue? the table is literally 0.008MB why would it be spread out across the disk?